# I have problem to pass data from from android app to webview form

Tags: android, webview

I have data in Main Activity and then I want to pass the value to WebView that have form with input type as text.

How can I pass that value to input type as text.

Answer (score 2):

You can call javascript methods after the web page is loaded.
Take a look at the following sample.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("yourURL.html");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){   
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:foo('" + argumentsToPass + "')");
    }           
});
```

This code will call a JS foo function after the page is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(val){
    // val is the parameters you passed
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this code write in web or in android app

<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(val){
    // val is the parameters you passed
    }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Main Class:

```
 String data = "hello";

 //MAKE INTENT WITH CONTEXT AND TARGET CLASS
 Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), WebView.class );
 //ASSIGN VARIABLE AND DATA TO BE PASSED
 intent.putExtra( "Variable", data );
 //START THE ACTIVITY
 startActivity(intent);
```

WebView Class:

```
 //DECLARE INTENT TO GET DATA
 Intent i = getIntent();
 //GET VALUE OF VARIABLE ASSIGNED AND SAVE IT TO STRING
 String url = i.getStringExtra("Variable");
```